# How to test the input impedance of a Microphone Preamp?

Tags: microphone, input-impedance, preamp

How would someone test the input impedance of a microphone preamp? I have all the necessary equipment i.e. oscilloscope and multi-meters but I'm struggling to find information on the topic.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a preamp has negligible reactive impedance:

Apply oscillating voltage signal of known amplitude. Measure current. Divide. Done!

If trying to do things right: do the same over a range of frequencies.